# how to get connected metaMask Wallet privateKey Dynamically In Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, payment, metamask, wallet

currently I Am Using https://pub.dev/packages/web3dart package for send transaction and need metaMask wallet privateKey. how can i get PrivateKey

transactionForAddProduct({String? functionName, var params, Web3Client? web3client}) async {

```
try {
  DeployedContract _contract = await loadContract();
  final sendFunction = contract.function(functionName!);
  Transaction transaction = Transaction.callContract(
    from: EthereumAddress.fromHex("walletAddress"),
    contract: _contract,
    function: _sendFunction,
    parameters: params,
  );
  var transactionValue = web3client!.sendTransaction(
    EthPrivateKey.fromHex("privateKey"),
    transaction,
    chainId: 80001,
    fetchChainIdFromNetworkId: false,
  );
  print("=====> transaction is ${transactionValue}");
} catch (exception) {
  print("=======> exception is ${exception.toString()}");
}
```

}